# What are the benefits of switching from Rule and /. to OptionsPattern[] and OptionValue in a large application?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

Old habits die hard, and I realise that I have been using `opts___Rule` pattern-matching and constructs like `thisoption /. {opts} /. Options[myfunction]` in the very large package that I'm currently developing. Sal Manango's "Mathematica Cookbook" reminds me that the post-version-6 way of doing this is `opts:OptionsPattern[]` and `OptionValue[thisoption]`. The package requires version 8 anyway, but I had just never changed the way I wrote this kind of code over the years.

Is it worth refactoring all that from my pre-version-6 way of doing things? Are there performance or other benefits?

Regards

Verbeia

**EDIT: Summary**

A lot of good points were made in response to this question, so thank you (and plus one, of course) all. To summarise, yes, I should refactor to use `OptionsPattern` and `OptionValue`. (NB: `OptionsPattern` not `OptionPattern` as I had it before!) There are a number of reasons why:

1. It's a touch faster (@Sasha)
2. It better handles functions where the arguments must be in `HoldForm` (@Leonid)
3. `OptionsPattern` automatically checks that you are passing a valid option to that function (`FilterRules` would still be needed if you are passing to a different function (@Leonid)
4. It handles `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) much better (@rcollyer)
5. It handles nested lists of rules without using `Flatten` (@Andrew)
6. It is a bit easier to assign multiple local variables using `OptionValue /@ list` instead of having multiple calls to `someoptions /. {opts} /. Options[thisfunction]` (came up in comments between @rcollyer and me)

**EDIT: 25 July** I initially thought that the one time using the `/.` syntax might still make sense is if you are deliberately extracting a default option from another function, not the one actually being called. It turns out that this is handled by using the form of `OptionsPattern[]` with a list of heads inside it, for example: `OptionsPattern[{myLineGraph, DateListPlot, myDateTicks, GraphNotesGrid}]` (see the "More information" section in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OptionsPattern.html)). I only worked this out recently.

Comment: @Sasha, @rcollyer, @AndrewMoylan: these are all great points, thanks! To summarise so far, yes I should refactor if I get time because (1) it's faster (@Sasha); (2) it handles nested lists (@Andrew); and (3) it handles RuleDelayed. I should add a fourth: it simplifies the code to set local variables for lots of options at once (i.e. {opt1, opt2, opt3} = {OptionValue[myOption1], OptionValue[myOption2],OptionValue[myOption2]}).

Comment: missed that one. The "lazy person" in me says that can be simplified further: `{opt1, opt2, opt3} = OptionValue /@ { ... }`.  Also, to add to your summary, `OptionsPattern[]` and `OptionValue[]` produce cleaner code.

Comment: duh! of course :-) Anyway I'll sit on these for a day, since it is not obvious which of these answers is the "best". They are all helpful, thanks! I am convinced to refactor now.

Comment: Regardless of which way you end up with to handle options, if your package is *very* large, then it may make sense to split it into two or more packages according to the "low coupling - high cohesion" principle. I found empirically that for me it starts becoming difficult to maintain and evolve a package once it grows to more than 1000 lines of code. And b.t.w., WorkBench helps a lot for large projects.

Comment: Thank you to whoever pushed this question over the line to 10 up votes.

Comment: @Verbeia - Fabulous question and summary. Current documentation really should include some more examples and explain the evolution from OptionQ to OptionsPattern. (1) Does anyone else find it odd that Workbench 2.0's Option 'quick-fix' steers users toward OptionQ (without explaining why)?? (2) Sometimes examples of OptionsPattern actually 'name' the pattern---e.g., opts:OptionsPattern[]---what are the benefits and pitfalls of doing so? (I rarely name patterns used in the heads of expressions; I think due to some global conflicts that arose... should named patters be Protected?)

Comment: @telefunkenvf14 I continue to name my OptionsPatterns - always `opts` - out of habit, and for those rare cases where I want to pass a whole bunch of options to a supporting function, e.g. in a hypothetical `mySpecialPlot`, you just want to filter the options that are valid for `ListPlot` or whatever, and pass that to the underlying function. You can't use `OptionValue` for that because you don't know in advance which options the user has set.

Comment: @Verbeia - Thanks. I'm starting to get it now. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While several answers have stressed different aspects of old vs. new way of using options, I'd like to make a few additional observations. The newer constructs `OptionValue` - `OptionsPattern`  provide more safety than `OptionQ`, since `OptionValue` inspects a list of global Options to make sure that the passed option is known to the function. The older `OptionQ` seems however easier to understand since it is based only on the standard pattern-matching and isn't directly related to any of the global properties. Whether or not you want this extra safety provided by any of these constructs is up to you, but my guess is that most people find it useful, especially for larger projects.

One reason why these type checks are really useful is that often options are passed as parameters by functions in a chain-like manner, filtered,  etc., so without such checks some of the pattern-matching errors would be very hard to catch since they would be causing harm "far away" from the place of their origin.

In terms of the core language, the `OptionValue` - `OptionsPattern` constructs are an addition to the pattern-matcher, and perhaps the most "magical" of all its features. It was not necessary semantically, as long as one is willing to consider options as a special case of rules. Moreover, `OptionValue` connects the pattern-matching to `Options[symbol]` - a global property. So, if one insists on language purity, rules as in `opts___?OptionQ` seem easier to understand - one does not need anything except the standard rule-substitution semantics to understand this:

```
f[a_, b_, opts___?OptionQ] := Print[someOption/.Flatten[{opts}]/.Options[f]]
```

(I remind that the `OptionQ` predicate was designed specifically to recognize options in the older versions of Mathematica), while this:

```
f[a_, b_, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := Print[OptionValue[someOption]]
```

looks quite magical. It becomes a bit clearer when you use `Trace` and see that the short form of `OptionValue` evaluates to a longer form, but the fact that it automaticaly determines the enclosing function name is still remarkable.

There are a few more consequences of `OptionsPattern` being a part of the pattern language. One is the speed improvements discussed by @Sasha. However, speed issues are often over-emphasized (this is not to detract from his observations), and I expect this to be especially true for functions with options, since these tend to be the higher-level functions, which will likely have non-trivial body, where most of the computation time will be spent.

Another rather interesting difference is when one needs to pass options to a function which holds its arguments. Consider a following example:

```
ClearAll[f, ff, fff, a, b, c, d];
Options[f] = Options[ff] = {a -> 0, c -> 0};
SetAttributes[{f, ff}, HoldAll];
f[x_, y_, opts___?OptionQ] :=
   {{"Parameters:", {HoldForm[x], HoldForm[y]}}, {" options: ", {opts}}};
ff[x_, y_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
   {{"Parameters:", {HoldForm[x], HoldForm[y]}}, {" options: ", {opts}}};
```

This is ok:

```
In[199]:= f[Print["*"],Print["**"],a->b,c->d]
Out[199]= {{Parameters:,{Print[*],Print[**]}},{ options: ,{a->b,c->d}}}
```

But here our `OptionQ`-based function leaks evaluation as a part of pattern-matching process:

```
In[200]:= f[Print["*"],Print["**"],Print["***"],a->b,c->d]
During evaluation of In[200]:= ***
Out[200]= f[Print[*],Print[**],Print[***],a->b,c->d]
```

This is  not completely trivial. What happens is that the pattern-matcher, to establish a fact of match or non-match, must evaluate the third `Print`, as a part of evaluation of `OptionQ`, since `OptionQ` does not hold arguments. To avoid the evaluation leak, one needs to use `Function[opt,OptionQ[Unevaluated[opt]],HoldAll]` in place of `OptionQ`. With `OptionsPattern` we don't have this problem, since the fact of the match can be established purely syntactically:

```
In[201]:= ff[Print["*"],Print["**"],a->b,c->d]
Out[201]= {{Parameters:,{Print[*],Print[**]}},{ options: ,{a->b,c->d}}}

In[202]:= ff[Print["*"],Print["**"],Print["***"],a->b,c->d]
Out[202]= ff[Print[*],Print[**],Print[***],a->b,c->d]
```

So, to summarize: I think choosing one method over another is largely a matter of taste - each one can be used productively, and also each one can be abused. I am more inclined to use the newer way, since it provides more safety, but I do not exclude that there exist some corner cases when it will surprise you - while the older method is semantically easier to understand. This is something similar to C-C++ comparison (if this is an appropriate one): automation and (possibly) safety vs. simplicity and purity. My two cents.

Answer (score 13):

It seems like relying on pattern-matcher yields faster execution than by using `PatternTest` as the latter entails invocation of the evaluator. Anyway, my timings indicate that some speed-ups can be achieved, but I do not think they are so critical as to prompt re-factoring.

```
In[7]:= f[x__, opts : OptionsPattern[NIntegrate]] := {x, 
  OptionValue[WorkingPrecision]}

In[8]:= f2[x__, opts___?OptionQ] := {x, 
  WorkingPrecision /. {opts} /. Options[NIntegrate]}

In[9]:= AbsoluteTiming[Do[f[1, 2, PrecisionGoal -> 17], {10^6}];]

Out[9]= {5.0885088, Null}

In[10]:= AbsoluteTiming[Do[f2[1, 2, PrecisionGoal -> 17], {10^6}];]

Out[10]= {8.0908090, Null}

In[11]:= f[1, 2, PrecisionGoal -> 17]

Out[11]= {1, 2, MachinePrecision}

In[12]:= f2[1, 2, PrecisionGoal -> 17]

Out[12]= {1, 2, MachinePrecision}
```

Comment: Interesting results. While this is logical, it never occurred to me that the difference may be so significant. +1

Answer (score 12):

A little known (but frequently useful) fact is that options are allowed to appear in nested lists:

```
In[1]:= MatchQ[{{a -> b}, c -> d}, OptionsPattern[]]

Out[1]= True
```

The options handling functions such as [FilterRules](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FilterRules.html) know about this:

```
In[2]:= FilterRules[{{PlotRange -> 3}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  MaxIterations -> 5}, Options[Plot]]

Out[2]= {PlotRange -> 3, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}
```

[OptionValue](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OptionValue.html) takes it into account:

```
In[3]:= OptionValue[{{a -> b}, c -> d}, a]

Out[3]= b
```

But [ReplaceAll (/.)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) doesn't take this into account of course:

```
In[4]:= a /. {{a -> b}, c -> d}

During evaluation of In[4]:= ReplaceAll::rmix: Elements of {{a->b},c->d} are a mixture of lists and nonlists. >>

Out[4]= a /. {{a -> b}, c -> d}
```

So, if you use [OptionsPattern](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OptionsPattern.html), you should probably also use OptionValue to ensure that you can consume the set of options the user passes in.

On the other hand, if you use ReplaceAll (/.), you should stick to `opts___Rule` for the same reason.

Note that `opts___Rule` is also a little bit too forgiving in certain (admittedly obscure) cases:

Not a valid option:

```
In[5]:= MatchQ[Unevaluated[Rule[a]], OptionsPattern[]]

Out[5]= False
```

But `___Rule` lets it through:

```
In[6]:= MatchQ[Unevaluated[Rule[a]], ___Rule]

Out[6]= True
```

Update: As **rcollyer** pointed out, another more serious problem with `___Rule` is that it misses options specified with [RuleDelayed (:>)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuleDelayed.html). You can work around it (see rcollyer's answer), but it's another good reason to use OptionValue.

Comment: I think it makes more sense to compare `OptionsPattern[]` with `___?OptionQ`, which was designed to check for options and handles the above examples fine, rather than with `___Rule` (although this is indeed the construct that the OP mentions). Also, in the past, there *was* a recommended way to deal with nested lists of options, which was to use OptionName/.Flatten[{opts}]/.Options[function]`, as described e.g. in the book of Roman Maeder "Programming in Mathematica" - so this is not a limitation of an older approach either.

Comment: @Leonid, I forgot about `OptionQ`. You're right, definitely superior to `___Rule`.

Comment: @Leonid: very good point. I remember switching from `OptionQ to `Rule` at some stage in the last 15 years in response to what I thought was the prefered way of doing things, around version 5, I guess. Looks like I need to catch up. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Your code itself has a subtle, but fixable flaw.  The pattern `opts___Rule` will not match options of the form `a :> b`, so if you ever need to use it, you'll have to update your code.  The immediate fix is to replace `opts___Rule` with `opts:(___Rule | ___RuleDelayed)` which requires more typing than `OptionsPattern[]`.  But, for the lazy among us, `OptionValue[...]` requires more typing than the short form of `ReplaceAll`. However, I think it makes for cleaner reading code.

I find the use of `OptionsPattern[]` and `OptionValue` to be easier to read and instantly comprehend what is being done.  The older form of `opts___ ...` and `ReplaceAll` was much more difficult to comprehend on a first pass read through. Add to that, the clear [timing advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617511/what-are-the-benefits-of-switching-from-rule-and-to-optionpattern-and-option/6618365#6618365), and I'd go with updating your code.